# Run WebApp from folder with BATCH

Tags: java, windows, spring, batch-file, tomcat

i'm new, nice to meet you! 
I made a web application java/spring based that runs with Apache Tomcat.
I'd like to do a particular thing, run this web application in every Pc without install Tomcat and set Environments Variables...
I tryed this:

- I created a folder with in  two tomcat folders: one with Tomcat 8.0.21
  (32 bit) and      the other one with Tomcat 8.0.28 (64 bit);
- A batch file that checks if the CPU is 32 or 64 bit, and runs the
  relative Tomcat startup.bat

Here is the batch code:

```
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86 (
  call apache-tomcat-8.0.21\bin\startup.bat 
) else (
  call apache-tomcat-8.0.28\bin\startup.bat 
)

timeout /T 60

start /wait http://localhost:8080/Project_name/
```

Timeout command is done to wait tomcat's startup.

I understand that this thing is very very strange but I really need to do it...

There's a way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What's your exact problem?

Comment: I have a web application that i'd like to use like a stand-alone application...
I'd like to start it from a folder using tomcat and using a batch file like an .exe

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a file for 32/64 bit computers. If other computers are on your same network then you can access from any of your network computer by accessing http://yourcomputer:8080/yourAppName (:8080 default port or whatever you set as default port)

Comment: Please always mark answer if it fixed your problem so that others can also get benefit if they faced same situation that you were having.